# "No APIs published yet" - wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2

I am using wos2 apimanager 1.6 connected to a mysql database.

When I login to the store I can see "No APIs published yet" on the home page. But I have published api from the store. When I click on the APIs tab I can see the APIs listed their, so why not on the home page.

See the image for reference:
[image]

I have also noticed the following logs while the startup script runs

```
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,176]  INFO - API Initializing API: admin--ankitTest:v1
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,176]  INFO - API Initializing API: provider1--YoutubeFeeds:v1.0.0
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,176]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMTokenAPI_
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,176]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI_
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,176]  INFO - API Initializing API: admin--apitest:v1
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,177]  INFO - API Initializing API: admin--test:v1
[2014-04-28 16:54:51,177]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMRevokeAPI_
```

These are not the APIs that I had published,neither are these seen on store nor are these found in the mysql-db. So from where are these APIs picked up?

**Update:**
I have found that these are pickup from the location: API_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api

Whenever I add new API the are visible only in the Recently Added column not in the APIs tab.

Also when I try to search api name in the search bar (on store) it searches.

Answer (score 3):

We are storing the APIs which are shown from publisher and store app in embedded registry  database of WSO2 AM.You can browse your created APIs from access management console [/carbon]  ,navigate to Home->Resources->Browse and navigate to registry path `_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/{user}`,you'll see APIs have been stored in there.

There's a solr based indexing process happening, once a user change the status of an API from publisher.This indexing process is happening periodically [every 5s] and we are showing filtered APIs from this indexed process in the Store middle section of UI.Why we are doing this to get paginated APIs list with increasing Store APIs loading time. Hence there will be a around 5s delay of showing the APIs in Store middle section.If you try refreshing the Store page,you will see your published API in middle section. 
The 5 APIs shown in 'Recently Added APIs' section is taking from a sql query directly.That's why the APIs shown in there first.

Additionally in WSO2 APIM,we are shipping three default APIs as *WSO2AMTokenAPI*,*WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI* and *WSO2AMRevokeAPI*.These will not display in publisher/store,rather those are to expose APIM integrated oauth2 functionalities which explained in https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Token+API.

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Answer (score 0):

this can be happen due to cache, This can be happen once you change your Lifecycle to another status and save.

You need to check whether LifeCycle of particular app status to PUBLISHED on publisher, save it.

Clear cache by pressing ctrl + F5

Comment: I dont think it is a cache issue. Because once I change status of API to published it appears in the recently added section of the store but not in the APIs tab

Comment: did you check the check box on lifecycle mgt ? i had same issue once and that will get fix after refresh cache

Comment: you mean the "Propagate Changes to API Gateway" check box?? Yes I always make sure that it is checked